# Prove using algebra of continuous functions that $f$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

> Let us consider $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
>   $$f(x) =\begin{cases} x^2 \sin \frac{1}{x},& x \neq 0\\ 0,& x = 0\end{cases}.$$
>
> By using algebra of continuous functions (or algebra of limits) show that $f$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$. (You may assume without
>   proving that $\sin y$ and polynomials are continuous at every point).

Okay so I understand that $x^2$ and $\sin\frac{1}{x}$ are both continuous functions, and due to algebra of continuous functions proving $f(x)$ is continuous but I'm not sure how to prove this? Thanks.

Comment: @Dr.MV,why not $\left| \sin { \left( \frac { 1 }{ x }  \right)  }  \right| \le \left| \frac { 1 }{ x }  \right| $ istead of $\le 1$?

Comment: @Battani The absolute value of the sine function is bounded by $1$.  Of course we can also use $|\sin z|<|z|$.  Either way permits us to demonstrate continuity.

Comment: @Dr.MV,i know that sine is bounded by 1)I think Lauren Bathers asked to show continuty at R,not at $0$ point

Comment: @Dr.MV Yes looking to show continuity across R (all real numbers)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differentiability of $f(x) = x^2 \sin{\frac{1}{x}}$ and $f'$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393602/differentiability-of-fx-x2-sin-frac1x-and-f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $y\ne0$, $x\mapsto x^2$ and $x\mapsto \sin\frac1x$ are continuous at $y$, so their product is as well.

For $y = 0$, recall that $\left|\sin\frac1y\right|\leqslant 1$, so $|f(y)|\leqslant y^2$. Given $\varepsilon>0$, $|y|<\varepsilon^{\frac12}$ implies that $$|f(y)|\leqslant y^2<\varepsilon,$$ so that $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Comment: could you explain the y=0 bit to me. where did the $y^2$ come from, and why does proving it to be less than epsilon prove it continuous at 0?

Comment: @LaurenBathers Do you remember the $\epsilon, \delta$ definition of continuity?  If so, here the $\delta$ is $\sqrt{\epsilon}$.  When $|y - 0| = |y| < \sqrt{\epsilon}$, then $|f(y) - f(0)| = |f(y) - 0| = |f(y)| < y^{2} < \sqrt{\epsilon}^{2} = \epsilon$.

Comment: Also, since $\sin(\text{anything})$ is always $\leq 1$, then $x^{2} \sin(\frac{1}{x}) \leq x^{2}(1) = x^{2}$, right? That's why $|f(y)| \leq y^{2}$.  As @Battani below me explains, this answer really only shows continuity at $x = 0$.  But when $x \neq 0$, since $x^{2}$ is continuous at any $x$ and $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is continuous at any $x \neq 0$, then their product is also continuous at any $x \neq 0$.  Here, we are using that the composition of continuous functions ($\sin(x)$ and $\frac{1}{x}$) and product of cts fcns ($x^{2}$ and $\sin(\frac{1}{x}$) are cts).

Comment: what about contionus at R?OP asked to show it at R

Comment: @Battani Check out my comment above yours.