# Continuity of $e^{-1/x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-1/{x^2}} & x\neq0\\ 0 & x=0\end{cases}$$

1. Show $f(x)$ is continuous
2. Show that the $n$-th derivative is continuous.

I've seen this a couple of ways but I'm struggling with an epsilon delta proof of the the first part. I know (in theory) how to get the second part once I have that.

Comment: You may want to check this out: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119858/infinitely-differentiable-function. Cheers!

Comment: Yea I get that part. My problem is first doing the epsilon delta proof of the first part.

Comment: Let $\delta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\ln(1/\epsilon)}}$